# Model parameter in Junit test method

Tags: spring-mvc, model, junit, controller

I'm new here and I'm learning Spring-MVC and Junit.

I'm trying to implement the test methods with Junit for this basic controller method:

```
public String home(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute(new Contact());
        logger.info("Welcome home!");
        return "home";
    }
```

And the test method is the following:

```
public void testHome() throws Exception{
        ContactsController contactsController=new ContactsController();
        Assert.assertEquals("home",contactsController.home(new Model()));
    }
```

The problem is, since Model is an interface I'm obviously not able to create a new Model object to pass it as a parameter to contactsController.home(...). What options would you give me? I have no idea what to do.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to pass an implementation of `Model`, such as `ExtendedModelMap`:

```
public void testHome() throws Exception{
    ContactsController contactsController=new ContactsController();         
    Assert.assertEquals("home",contactsController.home(new ExtendedModelMap()));
}
```

Comment: yeah but then the types won't match. So does that mean that I have to change the parameter type as well in the controller method implementation??

Comment: @Neets: Types would match, since `ExtendedModelMap` implements `Model`.

Comment: thanks!! I made that observation because I had already tried that with ModelMap and it didn't work, but it does work with ExtendedModelMap. So thanks for your help =)

Answer (score 1):

I know its so old.. but if someone has same problem just use @Mock annotation to initialize Model object. sth like:

```
@Mock
Model model;

@BeforeEach
void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

then just use model as you desired